# Threads cannot start in android

Tags: android

I have a problem with my `Thread`, the Thread doesn't start, I don't have any idea why it doesn't run.

This is my code,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv;
int seg=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.reloj);
}

boolean on=false;
public void inicia(View view){
    if(!on){
        tiempo.start();
        on=true;
    }

}

Thread tiempo=new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            while(true){
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                seg++;
                tv.setText(seg+"");
            }

        }catch (InterruptedException e){

        }
    }
};
```

}

prints this error
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: this is some seriously weird code - what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You messed up with your `while-loop`.

Comment: What is your requirement? A Timer or something like that?

Comment: I changed the code

Answer (score 0):

Well first off I'm assuming you set an onClick in you xml to set inicia to be the click handler for the button.  Otherwise, that's part of your problem.

You thread is in an infinite loop.  The while loop would only exit if an interrupt occurred for some reason, and there's nothing that would do that.  If you want to post accio every second, the post needs to be inside the while loop.

Comment: i cannot think that the loop as the problem, i changed, "while(true)" with "while(seg<100)" , and the problem still

Comment: You may not be calling the thread at all, see my first paragraph.  But even if that's part of the problem I assure you the loop is also wrong.

Comment: Also, that change wouldn't fix your loop because seg isn't changed inside of it.  Here's how you debug something like this-  put a breakpoint inside your loop.  Put one inside the Runnable that does the update.  See which are hit.  You'll see that the handler is never hit because you never post to it, and that you loop infinitely on the thread.

Comment: Then what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`while(true){
      Thread.sleep(1000);
}`

The thread is sleeping all the time.

Comment: i changed part of code, i move
seg++;
            System.out.println(seg+"");
            tv.setText(""+seg);

Comment: to intto the loop, but when i press many times the button, the threads starts

Comment: i put the while, so seg++, if i delete while(true), only prints 1 time, i need prints many times

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets try,

Thread will be created from the main looprer thread. So, Your textview will be updated only by mainlooper thread,. When you create the thread, it will start become another thread. it is not related with MainLooper thread, You have to use Handler class to update the textView or use Asynctask or runOnUiThread method to update your text view.

```
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textview.settext("");
        }
    });
```